# batch file to symbolic link files from different folders into common folder

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, directory, mklink

I have been trying to make symbolic links from multiple sources.

I have a `reg.txt` file in the `new` directory as well as the sort.bat.

the `reg.txt` :-

> ```
> redcar1=123456
> greencar2=345678
> ```

In directory called `vehicles` with sub directories of 'reg_numbers' ie:- `123456`,
within that directory I have a sub directory called `keys`, or `key`, with a `*.txt` file.

I want to symbolic link all the 'reg_numbers' (parsing the `reg.txt` - changing the folder name in the process) directories into the `new` directory the sort.bat file is in, and all the `keys` or `Key` directory files (*.txt), into a common `keys` directory in the `new` folder

so say:-

- `D:\vehicles\123456\keys\this.txt`
- `D:\vehicles\345678\key\that.txt`

symbolic linked

- `e:\new\redcar1\`
- `e:\new\greencar2\`
- `e:\new\keys\this.txt`
- `e:\new\keys\that.txt`

sort.bat is in the new folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set NEWPATH=%~dp0
set OLDPATH=d:\vehicles

for /f %%d in ('dir /b %NEWPATH%\keys') do (
    if not "%%d"=="not.txt" del /Q "%NEWPATH%Keys\%%d" ::clean out files
)
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=="  %%a in (reg.txt) do (
    rmdir /Q "%NEWPATH%%%a" ::clean out dir
    mklink /D %NEWPATH%"%%a" %OLDPATH%\"%%b"
    for /f %%c in ('dir /b %OLDPATH%\%%b\keys' ) do (

    mklink %NEWPATH%Keys\"%%c" %OLDPATH%\"%%b"\"%%c" 
    )
)
```

It's probably a mess but it works for nearly everything but I cannot get the `that.txt` from `key` folder.

Comment: Suggest you name *sort.bat* to something else as it has the same name as *sort.exe* if you use the command `sort`. Perhaps a name that is more unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "NEWPATH=%~dp0"
set "OLDPATH=D:\vehicles"

for /f %%A in ('2^>nul dir /b /a-d "%NEWPATH%\keys"') do (
    if not "%%~A" == "not.txt" del /Q "%NEWPATH%\Keys\%%~A"
)

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ("%NEWPATH%\reg.txt") do (
    rmdir /Q "%NEWPATH%\%%~A"
    mklink /D "%NEWPATH%\%%~A" "%OLDPATH%\%%~B"

    for /f %%C in ('2^>nul dir /b "%OLDPATH%\%%~B\keys" "%OLDPATH%\%%~B\key"' ) do (
        mklink "%NEWPATH%\Keys\%%~C" "%OLDPATH%\%%~B\%%~C"
    )
)
```

This may help to get symlinks to the files `this.txt` and `that.txt`. You have a `keys` folder and a `key` folder, yet your code only searches the directory of one of them. So now `dir` will search both directories.

I also adjusted quoting and use `~` in the `for` variables to remove possible quotes. Backslashes added as path separators where needed.

The double quotes for the set commands is to ensure that the value does not include any trailing space that is invisible to see.

`2^>nul` in the `for` commands is to redirect stderr stream to `nul`, so output of no files found by `dir` will not be output.

`usebackq` in `for` options changes the rules for the command. Double quotes without `usebackq`, interprets a double quotes as a string, not a path. With `usebackq`, double quotes can be used on a path. `%~dp0` is a path that may have spaces so double quoting seems a good idea to add. View `for /?` for more help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and it works. As a beginner, i will research why you quoted the ```set ""``` and added ```'2^>nul``` and also ```usebackq```. i new i had missed the ```key``` folder, but could not work out how to add it.